# How do I configure syslog server in 10.10 desktop?

Tags: 10.10, syslog

As the title says, how can I setup syslog server in 10.10?

Where can I find the configuration files?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you mean **rsyslog**, configuration files for rsyslog are stored in

```
/etc/rsyslog.conf
/etc/rsyslog.conf.d/
```

configuration of **logrotate** is done in

```
/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
```

afterwards just restart rsyslog